# AccessViolationException outside Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, interop, access-violation

I'm developing a small C# winforms application that consumes an unmanaged C++ library. 
I have no access to the code of this library.

If I'm in Visual Studio and I runt my application, do my calls to the library everything is working find. Once I run CTRL + F5 I get an AccessViolationException. 
I did some testing, created another winforms application in .NET 2.0 (others were in .NET 4.0) and there I don't receive the AccessViolationException. So I thought i'd create a .net 2.0 class library in my .net 4.0 solution and consume that class lib. This didn't help, still I had the AccessViolationException.

Tried setting allow unsafe code, optimize code on and off but that didn't help.
Why am I getting the AccessViolationException once I'm out of debug mode?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you start the app with ctrl-F5 and then attach the debugger (Debug->Attach to Process) before it crashes?

Comment: Then it is working again
VS goes back into debug mode then
I was thinking, could it have something to do with assembly trust?

Comment: Where is your app code? Network drive?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same issue. To reproduce the problem in the debugger, I had to go to:

Tools\Options
Debugging\General

and disable: Suppress JIT optimization on module load (managed only).

Of course the problem would only appear for a  optimized code.

Comment: A very untimed comment: Most likely it has to do with rearangement of structs. Try to add the attribute [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] on top of your structs. A good start is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx .